# ActiveMQ web console doesn't work with embedded broker

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have an embedded broker completely configured through java code (no deployable xml files). When I point my browser to the web console I just get a 404, and an lsof shows that nothing is listening on 8161. Is it possible to use the web console with only java code? I'm fine with using the webserver that comes with ActiveMQ, and I'm fine with the 8161 port.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Java code and not using Spring then just create your own servlet container yourself and register the admin WAR inside it.

This [example shows how to do it in Java code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/activemq/trunk/activemq-web-console/src/test/java/org/apache/activemq/web/tool/Main.java?view=markup) which is taken from the source of the web console.

It will probably take you quite a few trial and errors to get all the required jars on your classpath mind you - you'll need all of Jetty, JSP, Serlvets, JSTL and more - plus the ActiveMQ stuff too